# Why does the Telerik UI TableCell for PDF processing not honor CanWrapContent?

Tags: c#, telerik, pdf-generation

[CanWrapContent](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/api/Telerik.Windows.Documents.Flow.Model.TableCell.html#Telerik_Windows_Documents_Flow_Model_TableCell_CanWrapContent) is not being honored. The first column with content "ClientName:" should not wrap when I set `CanWrapContent` to false.

I'm using Telerik UI R1 2019

Generated PDF screenshot:

[image]

```
public void Mcve()
{
    Telerik.Windows.Documents.Flow.FormatProviders.Pdf.PdfFormatProvider provider = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Flow.FormatProviders.Pdf.PdfFormatProvider();

    RadFlowDocument document = new RadFlowDocument();
    RadFlowDocumentEditor editor = new RadFlowDocumentEditor(document);

    Table t = editor.InsertTable();

    TableCell cell0 = new TableCell(document);            
    cell0.CanWrapContent = false; // <------------ Ignored?
    cell0.Blocks.AddParagraph().Inlines.AddRun("ClientName:");

    TableCell cellLong = new TableCell(document);
    cellLong.Blocks.AddParagraph().Inlines.AddRun("Nullam sit amet dui porta, imperdiet quam sit amet, consequat diam. In vel orci rutrum, vehicula purus ullamcorper, ornare lorem. Sed at arcu ultrices, fringilla augue in, condimentum quam. Sed pretium faucibus");

    var row = t.Rows.AddTableRow();
    row.Cells.Add(cell0);
    row.Cells.Add(cellLong);

    using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("sample.pdf"))
    {
        provider.Export(document, output);
    }
    Process.Start("sample.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported:

[The CanWrapContent property is currently supported when exporting to DOCX and RTF. The PdfFormatProvider class doesn't provide this functionality and we have logged in our backlog:](https://www.telerik.com/forums/tablecell-not-honoring-canwrapcontent#Vo61TVXO_k29MCuBSppZnA)